# Continuity limit of signam function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity

> Question: Show that the signam function is not continuous.

The definition for a continuous function on a metric space.

> Def:
>
> Let $\left ( X,d \right )$ and $\left ( Y,e \right )$ be metric spaces.
>
> Let $f:\left ( X,d \right )\rightarrow \left ( Y,e \right )$
>   be a function and let $a \in X$.
>
> f is called continuous if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0 $s.t 
>   $f\left ( B_{\delta}\left ( a \right ) \right )\subseteq B_{\epsilon }\left ( f\left ( a \right ) \right )$

$Sgn\left ( x \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & if x>0\\ 
0 &if x=0 \\ 
-1 &if x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Let $\delta =\frac{\epsilon }{2}.$

The openball $B_{\delta}\left ( a \right )$ consists of all element x in the open interval from $\left ( a-\delta,a+\delta \right )$ since
$d\left ( a,x \right )<\epsilon $
implies $\left | a-x \right |<\epsilon $

For $a>x: a-x>\epsilon$ and so $x>a-\delta$

For $a<x:x-a>\epsilon$ and so $x<\delta +a$

$f\left ( B_{\epsilon }\left ( a \right ) \right )=f\left ( a-\delta,a+\delta \right )=\left ( 1,1 \right )$ for all $x >0$

I am unable to go further. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that $Sgn(x)$ is not continuous. Therefore, we need to **find** an $x$ and an $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$, $f(B_\delta(x)) \not \subseteq B_\epsilon(f(x)))$.

Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ and consider $x = 0$.

Now for any $\delta > 0$ , we have that $f(B_\delta(0)) = f((0 - \delta, 0 + \delta)) = f((-\delta, \delta)) = \{-1, 0 , 1\}$

However, we also have that $B_\epsilon (f(x)) = B_{\frac{1}{2}}(0)=(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Therefore, $f(B_\delta(x)) \not \subseteq B_\epsilon(f(x)))$ and we are done.

Comment: What determines our investigative value for $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Mathematicing: Are you asking why we chose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ or are you asking why we fixed an epsilon? To answer the former, there is no reason in general. Over time, it becomes easier to pick out "which $\epsilon$'s are the right ones". For the latter question, it follows from the order of quantifiers in the definition of continuity. We are simply negating the definition and thus need to ensure the existence of some $\epsilon$.

Comment: I was asking why you chose $\epsilon$=1/2. Does it makes my 'job' harder for choosing the 'wrong' value?

Comment: @Mathematicing: Well, if you choose epsilon too big, the argument doesn't work. Try considering $\epsilon = 4$. Your "job" is to find some $\epsilon$ such that the negation of the statement holds. In general, there is no way to know exactly how small of an $\epsilon$ you need to pick. The intuition of "how small an $\epsilon$ you need" comes over time.

Comment: @Mathematicing: Notice that there was nothing "inherently" special about $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. You can choose any $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 1$.